# HaProxy redirect Mysql traffic for a time interval

Tags: haproxy, cluster, mariadb

I have a MariaDB cluster with HaProxy. I need to redirect my clients to other machines everyday between 07.00-07.10 due to heavy working cronjobs. For example i have 3 server that ips are 192.168.1.2,192.168.1.3,192.168.1.4. between 07.00-07.10 my 192.168.1.1 application server shouldn't use 192.168.1.2. How can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

I think, easiest way is to use haproxy-agent. Example:

haproxy-section:

```
listen mysql
    bind *:3306
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    balance leastconn
    default-server port 3306 agent-check agent-port 6789 weight 100 inter 1000 on-marked-down shutdown-sessions
    server server1 192.168.1.2 check
    server server2 192.168.1.3 check
    server server3 192.168.1.4 check
```

/etc/xinet.d/haproxy-agent on mysql-hosts:

```
service haproxy-agent
{
    disable         = no
    flags           = REUSE
    log_on_failure  += USERID
    port            = 6789
    server          = /usr/local/bin/haproxy-agent
    socket_type     = stream
    type            = UNLISTED
    user            = nobody
    wait            = no
}
```

/usr/local/bin/haproxy-agent:

```
#!/bin/bash
RES="up 100%"
TIME=$(date "+%H%M" | sed 's/^0\+//')
[[ "${TIME}" -ge 700 && "${TIME}" -le 710 ]] && RES="down"
echo "${RES}"
```

Agent's code, of course, should be a little more intelligent not to overlap closing RDBMS-hosts. BTW, agent answer is optional to haproxy, so if it does not respond - ok, haproxy just ignore this fact.